# Does an injective function imply two sets have same cardinality?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

In the book "A first course in abstract algebra" by John B. Fraleigh, he states in the introduction chapter (which deals with sets and relations) that for two sets $X$ and $Y$, they have the same cardinality if there exists an one-to-one (injective) function between the two sets.

I'm not convinced about that since, if I understand the definitions correct, a one-to-one correspondence does not necessarily mean that the range is the same as the codomain, i.e. even if all $x \in X$ maps uniquely to $Y$, there might be elements in $Y$ that never gets mapped to (thus not same cardinality).

Have I missed something here or is Fraleigh wrong in that statement?

Comment: One to one correspondence normally means bijective

Answer (score 3):

Using [Google Books](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=xb0ZAQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=cardinality), the correct definition from the book is this:

> **0.13 Definition** Two sets $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality if there exists a one-to-one function mapping $X$ onto $Y$, that is if there exists a one-to-one correspondence between $X$ and $Y$.

Notice the requirement that not only the function is one-to-one, but it is also required to be onto, so the range is the same as the codomain.

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Oh, maybe I've misunderstood. The questioner claims that there's a particular statement in the introduction. You found the definition in the book and quoted it, and I assumed this was *separate* from the alleged statement in the introduction. Are you actually saying that the questioner simply misreported what they saw in the book? That is, are you saying that nowhere does the author say two sets "have the same cardinality if there exists an one-to-one (injective) function between the two sets"? I was trying to address the right/wrongness of that alleged statement.

Comment: Yes, the OP mistook the definition for one where "onto" does not appear. And it's hard to blame them, it can be tricky for the untrained eye. I quoted the definition from the book and pointed out the mistake made by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

The terminology here is slightly confusing.

Usually a one-to-one *function* is an injective function (sometimes called an injection), but a one-to-one *correspondence* is a bijective function (often called a bijection). To avoid such confusion, I personally think it is better to use the terms *injective* and *bijective*.

As you point out, two sets $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality if there exists a bijection (i.e. a one-to-one correspondence) between them.